# There is no a normal self-dual base of $\mathbb{F}_{16}$ on $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

## How to prove that there is no a normal self-dual base of $\mathbb{F}_{16}$ on $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Imamura and Morii proved the nonexistence of normal self-dual bases when $q$ is even and $n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, but I can not find a proof of it.

Please help me.

Comment: $\Bbb F_{16}$ is small enough to try every element.

Comment: What means self-dual ?

Comment: It means autodual. A base is autodual if it is its own dual.